# updating javascript time every second

Tags: javascript, datetime

Basically I want to have a live clock, one that updates every second! I've looked around and couldn't find something that has worked. Here is what I have tried:

```
function doDate()
{
    var str = "";

    var days = new Array("Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday");
    var months = new Array("January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December");

    var now = new Date();

    str += "Today is: " + days[now.getDay()] + ", " + now.getDate() + " " + months[now.getMonth()] + " " + now.getFullYear();
    var updateTime = function() { setTimeout("doDate()", 1000); }

    document.getElementById("todaysDate").innerHTML = str;
}
```

This does not seem to work! I presume there is something I have done right in here?

Comment: This code has no effect: `var updateTime = function() { setTimeout("doDate()", 1000); }`

Comment: Ill add this as a comment, cause its more of a code-review issue than a part of the answer: Why not just use the `Date` object and parse it out as you wish to display it, instead of creating a bunch of arrays every time the timer ticks?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Please modify your code as follow:-

```js
function doDate()
{
    var str = "";

    var days = new Array("Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday");
    var months = new Array("January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December");

    var now = new Date();

    str += "Today is: " + days[now.getDay()] + ", " + now.getDate() + " " + months[now.getMonth()] + " " + now.getFullYear() + " " + now.getHours() +":" + now.getMinutes() + ":" + now.getSeconds();
    document.getElementById("todaysDate").innerHTML = str;
}

setInterval(doDate, 1000);
```

```html
<div id="todaysDate"></div>
```

Comment: "Try this" answers are not usually *useful*. Say *what* you changed, and more importantly, *why*.

Comment: Perfect answer! I forgot to add my actual time clock in my question! Im glad you understood what I was trying to do.

Comment: This code gives me answer in localTime how can I convert it to UTC Format. If I use to UTC function then .getDay() getDate() are throwing error.

Comment: This is nice, but you could simplify this and use locale to get translated strings, see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleDateString

Answer (score 4):

This line of code has no effect:

```
var updateTime = function() { setTimeout("doDate()", 1000); }
```

You define function variable `updateTime` which make postponed invocation of `doDate`, but this variable is unused in your code.

Instead of this you have to call `setTimeout` immediately without wrapping it with function:

```
setTimeout(doDate, 1000);
```

Answer (score 1):

following code might help you

```
function doDate()
{
    var str = "";
    var now = new Date();
    str = now.toDateString() +' '+now.toLocaleTimeString() ;
    document.getElementById("todaysDate").innerHTML = str;
}
setInterval(doDate, 1000);
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
function doDate() {
  let currentDate = document.getElementById('currentDate');
  let current = new Date();
  currentDate.innerHTML = `Current Date and Time : <b>${current}</b> `;
}

setInterval(doDate, 1000);
```

```html
<div id="currentDate"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your setTimeout call is incorrect:

```
var updateTime = function() { setTimeout("doDate()", 1000); }
```

Should rather look like:

```
setTimeout(doDate, 1000);
```

When adding a callback, you should not call the function (and in this case, you should not add it as a string), add the function itself.
And the function you wrap it inside of is not needed, just call the setTimeout function right away.